# How to learn QFT from mathematical perspective?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-field-theory

I want to learn QFT, because I have heard of its applications in mathematics, I am not interested in scattering cross sections and such. Where can I start to learn? Only books I found are either way above my level or too physics oriented.
I know undergraduate math level and have had courses in QM and SR and such. I found Folland's book abit too high level, there must be some easier arxiv papers or something.

Comment: This question is highly dependent on your background.

Comment: It's usually a prereq to have a really solid foundation in qm. Maybe starting with a graduate text on qm

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206613/how-to-learn-qft-from-mathematical-perspective